# Recursive sum method

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I don't understand how the outcome of the following code is `6`, when called as `sum(3)`. Can someone please explain?

```
public int sum(int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        return number;
    } else {
        return number + sum(number - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `3 + 2 + 1 == 6`

Comment: Better than our explaining it -- use your IDE debugger and step through the code to see for yourself what is happening, and how recursion is working here

Comment: You can also grab a piece of paper and play the algorithm step by step.

Answer (score 5):

Think about it this way: if I told you the `sum` of the previous `number`, could you tell me the `sum` of the current `number`? If I told you that `sum(4) = 10`, what's `sum(5)`? Well, clearly `sum(5) = 5 + sum(4) = 5 + 10 = 15`.

Here's another challenge: based on that, can you calculate `sum(7)`? Well, clearly `sum(7) = 7 + sum(6) = 7 + 6 + sum(5) = 7 + 6 + 15 = 28` - the fact that we already "know" the value of `sum(5)` means that we can directly substitute it in (at least for the purpose of our hand-calculation).

There you have it: if I give you an arbitrary number somewhere in the sequence, you know how later values in the sequence are related to it. You can then use that to generate more values. It just so happens that whoever wrote this originally gave us the first value in the sequence: `sum(1) = 1`. This (at least theoretically) allows us to generate the sum for any natural number.* (See caveat below).

Incidentally, the following `for` loop is basically equivalent:

```
public static int forSum(int number)
    {
        int ret = 0;

        for (int i = number; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            ret += i;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

I'd encourage you to step through this with your favorite debugger to convince yourself that that's the case.

Incidentally, the following may be helpful: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

`*` **Caveat**: In reality, we can't *actually* use this to generate the sum of any natural number because we'll eventually run into one of a couple of problems:

1. There are an infinite number of natural numbers, but only a finite amount of memory. (Note that infinity itself is not a natural number, nor even a real number, but rather a [hyperreal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)).
2. Eventually, the length of time that the computation would take would exceed the normal human lifespan. Calculating the sum of 10^10, for example, would take almost 167 hours (even if you did a million operations per second). Calculating the sum of 10^20 would take 190,258,751 *years* (i.e. over 190 *million* years) at 1000000 operations per second.
3. There's a hard limit to how big of a number an `int` can hold.

We still, however, have a mathematical specification of what the solution is: `sum(10^20) = 10^20 + sum(10^20 - 1)` - we just don't have the time to compute it.

Answer (score 4):

It's called recursion

If you will debug this code you will see something like:

```
step0: sum(3)
step1: 3 + sum(2)
step2: 3 + 2 + sum(1)
step3: 3 + 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation

The method sums up all values up to the given argument. The argument is `3`, the result is thus `6 = 3 + 2 + 1`.

Therefore, the method uses [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). That is, the method calls itself. It exploits the property that

```
sum(n) = n + sum(n - 1)
```

for any integer n.

---

### Iterative

Let's first take a look at an equivalent method that don't uses recursion:

```
public static int sum(int number) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = number; i >= 1; i--) {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Called with `3` the method has three iterations. It adds `3` to `result`, then `2` and finally `1`, resulting in `6`.

---

### Recursive

Your recursive method does a similar thing. It takes `3` and adds the result of `sum(2) = 2 + 1` to it. `sum(2)` is computed with the same technique, it takes `2` and adds `sum(1) = 1` to it. `sum(1)` itself does not trigger another computation since it does not call `sum` again, take a look at your code:

```
if (number == 1)
    return number;
```

Again, let's take a look at the code:

```
return number + sum(number - 1);
```

So calling with `3` yields `3 + sum(3 - 1)`, which is `3 + sum(2)`. In order to compute this, the method `sum` must be called again, with the argument `2`. Calling with `2` yields `2 + sum(1)`. In order to compute this, the method is called with `1`. The call returns `1`.

Substituting everything back yields:

```
sum(3) = 3 + sum(2)
       = 3 + (2 + sum(1))
       = 3 + (2 + (1))
       = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive method that outputs n+(n-1)+...+1. Thus, `sum(3)` outputs `3+2+1=6`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the sum method with argument 3. The call becomes 3 + sum (2). second calls become 2+sum(1), this second calls returns 1. so the expression 2+ sum(1) returns 3 and first call 3+sum(2) will return 6.